# What are the reasons to use npm scripts over Makefile?

Tags: npm, makefile, continuous-integration, react-scripts

I've started learning frontend development with a background of DevOps and Backend. It was common for me to use Makefile's to simplify automation. Let's examine the case on the example of linting.

If I were to specify a script for linting in frontend project now I would create a Makefile with following contents:

```
.PHONY: install_dev
install_dev:
    npm install --save-dev eslint eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-whitespace


.PHONY: eslint
eslint:
    npx eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx src

.PHONY: lint
lint: eslint
```

So on `make lint` in console, linting would happen in a way specified.

However, I've heard that I can specify custom scripts in `package.json`, in "scripts" section. Which way is better and why?

```json
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "npx eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx src", // ?? I'm not sure about syntax
},
```

I don't like that my packages information is mixed with my automation, however it seems like a standard in frontend development. I'm willing to figure it out and learn if it really is better! But I don't understand why it would be made that way.

What are the main reasons to choose npm scripts over Makefile?

p.s. I'm using create-react-app to setup the project.

Comment: Why introduce another tool (`make`) when the tool you are already using (`npm`) provides similar functionality? Your `Makefile` is very simple and doesn't use any functionality provided by `make`, except for running a recipe. Also, it is more about what is common practice in JavaScript/front-end development.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stop using Makefile for automation, especially if you have already practice with it, you can automate and do more than you can with npm scripts alone.

And as you normally control the package.json you can also decide when you want to add a script in there or when to keep it out there. I dunno if there are good suggestions when to do what, but for the one project I have with eslint, I at least only let it run if the target requires it. I'm using a sentinel file for that.

At the end of the day, its your project and every project is different, so make the build the best you can get.

And from practice with composer scripts - which I have more compared to npm - if you've overdone it once with the scripts, you get a pretty good sense when to stop with them and go make. But that's just my 2 cents.